# Error installing 'gem install json --platform=ruby ' on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

When I run this command

```
C:\row\Ruby200\devkit>gem install json --platform=ruby --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

I get the error

```
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

What does this error mean and what can I do about it?

Comment: What is in `C:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out` file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the DevKit.

Here's a step by step guide:

http://www.systemroot.ca/2012/07/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-windows/